# Angular JS application localhost Path

Tags: angularjs, path, localhost

I have angular application located in directory `'someApp'`. Url is `http://example-domain/someApp/#/` on server. But my localhost application is running like `localhost:8000/#!`

Now I want my application to run same like server from localhost as well but I don't have idea how to do that, The problem is on server `someApp` is appended after host and my code like `href` links not and `stateProvider` is failing to load html files.

The application runs like `http://example-domain/someApp/#/` but when user clicks on create link it replaces the URL with `http://example-domain/#/create` and it fails

Html code is

```
<a href="/create">Create</a>
```

Please help to make both works same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, basically when running in dev locally it was working and then on the test server wasn't working anymore, or vice-versa.

- first suggestion: never use absolute path to define resources: use always relative path (service, links, files,....)
- Use locally as well as remotely the same directory structure, i.e. if remotly you have **/someApp** then create also locally a directory called **/someApp**: http://localhost:yourport/someApp/#! should then work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does that mean moving my all files under the someApp folder will resolve the problem ? Those requests are being served from root/app folder in my case. So what I'm confused is how to strat application with http://localhost:port/someApp/ ?

Comment: yes, just create a folder /someApp under the root folder of you localhost